# Is "drool" used correctly here? "I am all drools for this library"

Tags: word-usage, nouns

I need to understand, is 'drool' also used to express how you are in awe of something. Like, is this sentence right?

> I am all drools for this library. It has a great collection of books.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be understandable—but the noun *drool* isn't normally used that way. And anybody hearing it would find it strange.

Also, while I'd like to say that *adrool* is a word, I can't. Because it isn't.

---

However, something that *is* a word, and which fits your meaning, is [**agog**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agog):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : full of intense interest or excitement : EAGER
> // kids all *agog* over new toys

So, in your sentence, the closest expression that uses an entirely normal phrase is:

> I'm all *agog* over this library. It has a great collection of books.

Comment: One normally 'drools' at the thought of appetising food, or, by extension, something that offers physical gratification.